# Adding elements to dataTable only for viewing purposes

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm sorry about the confusing title, I really couldn't think of a better one.

I have the following problem:

I have a list in my view being shown on a `dataTable`, it all works fine. It's sort of a list of payments, so there is the payment value, form and other details.

Now the client wants me to order it by payment form, and add subtotals to it. The only way I thought of doing it, is adding new items to the list, so that they'll appear on the `dataTable` and it worked fine.

The issue is that these values only need to exist there for viewing purposes, so whenever I send the list back to the server for some processing, I need to ignore those values. I don't want to change all the code, so I thought I'd just remove 'em for processing, and add 'em again when returning to the view (because I need to update them after the processing aswell, so that I don't have inconsistent values).

What is the best way for me to do that? Identifying all points and invoking the methods? Perhaps creating a servlet filter for the job? Any suggestions?

Here's an example of how the table should look like:

[image: DataTable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show them as "footer" facet of the column instead of as part of the list. The footer is not evaluated on a per-row basis, but on a per-table basis, so you can safely bind it to properties of the backing bean itself instead of to the iterated list.

E.g.

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.payments}" var="payment">
    ...
    <h:column>
        #{payment.price}
        <f:facet name="footer">
            #{bean.subtotalPaymentPrice}
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

---

**Update**: as per the question update which includes a helpful screenshot which describes the requirement much better than those 1000 words in the question, no, this isn't "out the box" possible with standard JSF. Based on your question history you're using PrimeFaces or at least familiar with it, so you may find the `<p:subTable>` helpful. See also [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf).

Comment: I believe I didn't express myself very well, I'm sorry. I added an image to show how the datatable should look like, It already uses footer facet for total, the problem is with the subtotals. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, no easy way around it I imagine. I just didn't want to mess with the whole functionality just to add the subtotals. Is the servlet filter suggestion a completely smelly workaround?